# How to check that a Ruby file is empty?

Tags: ruby

I have a text file for example. What is the best way to check in Ruby that a file is empty?
`File.size('test.rb') == 0` looks ugly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615884/optimized-way-of-getting-the-size-of-a-response-in-ruby

Comment: IMHO that syntax explicitly states the intension of the code, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could use the [`zero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-zero-3F) method:

```
File.zero?("test.rb")
```

Comment: Less verbose than my version.

Answer (score 5):

`File.size?('test.rb')` evaluates to `nil` if the file is empty `or` it does not exist.  `File.zero?('test.rb')` will return true is the file is empty, but it will return false if the file is not found.  Depending on your particular needs you should be careful to use the correct method.

As an example in the topic creator's question they specifically asked, "What is the best way to check in Ruby that a file is empty?" The accepted answer does this correctly and will raise a `No such file or directory` error message if the file does not exist.

In some situations we may consider the lack of a file to be "equivalent" to an empty file.

Answer (score 4):

As of Ruby 2.4.0, there is [File.empty?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-empty-3F).

(Note that it always returns `false` if you pass it a directory, whether that directory is empty or not: `File.empty?('/') # => false`. So use [Dir.empty?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-empty-3F) for that instead, or [Pathname#empty?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-empty-3F) which works for both files and directories.)

Answer (score 2):

One different approach is to iterate over each line and do stuff for each iteration.  0 lines = 0 iterations = no extra code needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think should check like this:

```
def file_empty?(file_path) 
  !(File.file?(file_path) && !File.zero?(file_path))
end
```

so we do not need to worry about file exist or not.

File.zero?('test.rb') return false if file not exist